# Position absolute problen in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

inside position relative div I place position absolute div with top and left value, but it does not work in internet explorer 7. Please help

## CSS

```
.pagi_container {
background-color:#EEE;
border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
border-top:1px solid #CCC;
height:30px;
margin:0;
width:620px;
position:relative;
}
.pagi_container  form{
position:absolute;
top:5px;
right:10px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="pagi_container">
<form>
<b>Select your time zone: </b>
<select>
<option  value="America/Los_Angeles">United States (GMT-07:00)</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
<div class="sort-v3">
<ul>
<li class="first"> <strong>eCard Status</strong> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works as expected in Internet Explorer 7. Make sure you have a valid doctype and no mistakes in your markup or styling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Absolutely Positioned Elements in IE7</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .foo {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px; height: 100px;
        background: #f1f1f1;
      }
      .bar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 30px; height: 30px;
        top: 5px; left: 5px;
        background: #CCC;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="foo">
      <div class="bar">Bar</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1292594 It can be; depending on what effect you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @user1292594 You should edit your question to include any relevant code samples.